# 502 bad gateway nginx while acessing the server

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi, wsgi

I am creating a simple "Hello World app" using nginx + uwsgi + python. However, I am getting the bad gateway error in browser when I try to access using my server ip.

nginx error log shows:

```
2016/12/25 17:23:21 [crit] 10269#10269: *1 connect() to unix:///home/manish/pyapp/pyapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.161.59.236, server: 35.154.95.139, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/manish/pyapp/pyapp.sock:", host: "35.154.95.139"
```

Here are some files which I configured:

pyapp.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application

http-socket = :8080

master = true
processes = 5

socket = pyapp.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

pyapp/wsgi.py file

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return ["<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"]
```

Upstart file /etc/init/pyapp.conf

```
description "uWSGI instance to serve pyapp"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid manish
setgid www-data

script
    cd /home/manish/pyapp
    . pyappenv/bin/activate
    uwsgi --ini pyapp.ini
end script
```

nginx file

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/pyapp

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 35.154.95.139;

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/manish/pyapp/pyapp.sock;
    }
}
```

symbolik links

```
manish@ip-17-1-24-27:~/pyapp$ ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Dec 25 12:13 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Dec 25 16:42 pyapp -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/pyapp
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this question is stupid but.. have you enabled uwsgi with this socket?

Comment: the issue got resolved by installing upstart library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to missing upstart library. After installing the upstart file it worked.